# What is the preferred method for dealing with flags?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know that in C++, there are several ways to implement flags, such as `std::bitset<>`, `bool`, & using integer types like `uint8_t`. But when execution time or memory is limited, what is the preferred method of implementing flags in C++, like `for(;;)` vs `while(1)`

I assume that using `bool` or `char` is faster than `std::bitset<>` because `std::bitset` isn't a basic data type.

```cpp
std::bitset<2> flag;
flag.reset(0);
flag.set(1);
if(flag.test(0)){...}
if(!flag.test(1)){...}
//------------------------
bool flag0 = 0;
bool flag1 = 1;
if(flag0){...}
if(!flag1){...}
//------------------------
uint8_t flag = 0b00000010;
if(flag & 0x01){...}
if(!flag & 0x02){...}
```

I would personally use `uint8_t` when dealing with flags in a `struct` or if they would be used repeatedly during program execution, like a player's status effects, and `bool` for short-term flags, like when preforming a bubble sort.

*Are there other, more efficient, or more preferred ways to implement flags?*

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference would be between `bitset` and the `uint8_t` approach would be by the time an optimizing compiler is through with `bitset`. Remember that C++ describes behaviour and the compiler could discard whatever you actually coded and replace it with a couple of integers in registers. Hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

in my projects, when i have a lot of booleans in a class, i pack them like this.

```
class A {
    //...

    struct {   //note: unnamed struct
        bool bCondA : 1;
        bool bCondB : 1;
        bool bCondC : 1;
        //... and so on...

    };
    //...
};


void funcA(){

    A objA;
    if(A.bCondB){
        //...
    }
    else if (A.bCondC){
        //...
    }

}
```

you can use the member flags/boolean as usuals like ordinary bool member in any code. the edit will be on the class definition only.

if i want to manipulate multiple of them in a single operation, i do this:

```
class A {
    //...
    union {   //note: unnamed union
        struct {   //note: unnamed struct
            bool m_bCondA : 1;
            bool m_bCondB : 1;
            bool m_bCondC : 1;
            //... and so on...

        };
        int m_bAllFlags;   //note: you can change int to int8_t or any type that will fit all the flags.
    };

    void methodX(); //method for testing.
    void clearFlags(){ m_bAllFlags = 0; } //clear all flags in 1 swoop.
    void clearGroup1Flags(){ m_bAllFlags & ~0b0110101101; }
    //...
};


void A::methodX(){

    A objA;

    objA.m_bCondC = true;

    if(objA.m_bCondA){
        //...
    }
    else if (objA.m_bCondA){
        //...
    }

    objA.clearFlags();

}
```

i don't know what are the full list of advantages and disadvantages but it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

The standard data type for bits ("flags") is `bool`.

If you need a fixed-size array of bits, use `std::bitset`. If you need a variable-size array of bits, use `std::vector<bool>` (but beware: it is not really a `std::vector`, i.e. does not comply to a standard container interface).
Both of them pack bits, so they use minimal memory, but may not be the fastest. Both are usually more convenient than packing bits in integers and using bitwise operators like

```
uint8_t flag = 0b00000010;
if(flag & 0x01){...}
```

Finally, if you deal with pre-defined hardware registers, you may need to use a struct with bitfields, like

```
struct Flags
{
   unsigned f1 : 1;
   unsigned f2 : 1;
   //....
};
```